# SSAS Memory in use by Offline_

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, database-administration, ssas-tabular

I am using an excel workbook to check the memory usage of my SSAS with this DMV query:

```
Select * from $System.discover_object_memory_usage
```

After putting this in a pivottable it shows most memory is used by 3 objects/models called: `Offline_randomtextstring`

I checked my analyis server in SSMS and there is no offline model that could explain this. How can I figure out what this is and why it's using my memory?